Visual Studio Code bad formatting in vuejs
I've reinstalled my Windows again and installed Visual Studio Code along with Prettier, but it's formatting the syntax and everything else very poorly. Below is an example of how it looks and how it should be
This is the bad one
if (this.inter.total_quantity_inv != this.inter.invoice.quantity) {
  if (
    this.notice.notice_quantity >
    this.inter.invoice.quantity -
      this.inter.total_quantity_inv +
      initial_notice_quantity
  ) {
    this.notice.notice_quantity =
      this.inter.invoice.quantity -
      this.inter.total_quantity_inv +
      initial_notice_quantity;
    this.showThrottledError.call(
      this,
      "Cantitatea anexei nu poate depăși cantitatea facturii!"
    );
  }
}

This is the good one
if (this.inter.total_quantity_inv != this.inter.invoice.quantity) {
    if (this.notice.notice_quantity > this.inter.invoice.quantity - this.inter.total_quantity_inv + initial_notice_quantity) {
          this.notice.notice_quantity = this.inter.invoice.quantity - this.inter.total_quantity_inv + initial_notice_quantity;
          this.showThrottledError.call(this, "Cantitatea anexei nu poate depăși cantitatea facturii!");
    }
}

I've configured the prettier setting, but nothing, I've uninstalled and installed again, I've tried another formatter, but nothing work

Looks mostly like a print-width issue. You can see ways of configuring your stuff here. I also recommend that you sync your VScode settings through Github's gist system (baked-in nowadays). If you do not have any overriding configs in the new project, no reason for it to have a different behavior. Double-check that it is also configured to have the server applying to a Vue/babel JS syntax (bottom right).

Also, not sure what is the other formatter you tried but stick to Prettier's settings and also stop uninstalling etc. The issue is in the configuration of your code editor, probably not in the plugin itself. If you still have a device with a working config, feel free to upload it to your Github's gist. Otherwise, any kind of share of your current config might be very welcome too.

Try this all-in-one vuejs extension pack. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mubaidr.vuejs-extension-pack
It almost covers all the extensions that you need as a Vue developer.

This is not exactly a related issue at all.
